# Linking error: undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++, kde-plasma

My compiler reports this undefined reference to `openWallet(..)` function.  As you can see I have linked responding libraries `-L/usr/lib -lkdeui -kdecore -lkparts`.

Error:

```
password.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long long, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType)'
```

Compile command:

> g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o
>   password_client "ALL *.o FILES" -L/usr/lib -lkdecore -lkdeui -lkparts -lglib-2.0
>   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -lpthread

Same error is reported by QtCreator. `.pro` file contains

```
LIBS += -lkdecore \
        -lkdeui \
        -lkparts
```

I have all that required libs installed. Proof:

Output of `nm -D /usr/lib/libkdeui.so | grep openWallet` is :

> 000000000032df70 T
>   _ZN7KWallet6Wallet10openWalletERK7QStringmNS0_8OpenTypeE

As you can see there is that funcion in libkdeui.so file. ^^

I have installed libraries with:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-dev libkparts4
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Where is the mistake?

SSCCE:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <KWallet/Wallet>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    using namespace KWallet;

    Wallet* wallet = Wallet::openWallet(Wallet::LocalWallet(), 0);
    return a.exec();
}
```

`.pro` file:

```
QT       += core 

TARGET = untitled

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -lkdeui -lkdecore -lkparts

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KDE \
               /usr/include/KDE/KWallet
```

Compilation:

> g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG
>   -DQT_DBUS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/KDE -I/usr/include/KDE/KWallet -ITDIR/include/QtGui -ITDIR/include -I. -o main.o main.cpp
>
> g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o untitled main.o -L/usr/lib  -L/usr/X11R6/lib64
>   -lkdeui -lkdecore -lkparts -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL -lpthread

Comment: Can you provide an SSCCE reproducing the issue?

Comment: @lpapp I've edited the question, I had to update headers in kwallet.h because they were for old Qt. `#include <QtCore/QStringList>` -> `#include <QStringList>` etc.

Comment: Is it possible you have the 32 bit versions of the `KWallet` library installed? This will fail linking even though you've included them in the `LIBS` directive.

Comment: sometimes problem occurs when ordering of libraries is improper. Try to put `-lkdeui` as last command line parameter. Or at least try to `LIBS += -lkdecore -lkparts -lkdeui`

Comment: @TylerJandreau Well, I dont know, I've installed it through apt-get as everything else `apt-get install kdelibs5-dev libkparts`

Comment: @triclosan Nothing changed. Same linking error.

Comment: @tricolsan `apt-get` usually works just fine for 32/64 stuff. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are mixing up Qt 5 with KDE Frameworks 5. That is not going to fly like that. See this yourself:

```
KDE 4 related linkage: -lkdeui -lkdecore -lkparts
Qt 5 related linkage: -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core
```

The fix is relatively simple:

```
LIBS += -lkdecore -lkparts -lKF5Wallet
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Naturally, if you move onto KF5, you will also need to change the includepaths to:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    ...
    /usr/include/KF5 \
    /usr/include/KF5/KWallet/ \
    ...
```

You will need to link against that library should you be using Qt 5 and KF 5. Basically, you were using kde 4, as kdeui is a KDE 4 library. You can check that yourself by issuing the following command:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/libkdeui.so
```

In short, the `WId` was `unsigned long` in the kdeui library since that is what was used for this on X11 platforms, whereas the Qt 5 mix may have confused the `quintptr` in for the `WId`, somehow. While Qt 4's WId was different for different platforms, Qt 5's WId is `quintptr`, so that is clearer.

If you plan to use Qt 4 with KDE 4, your initial code is fine, but you need to make sure that you run Qt 4's qmake in that case as opposed to Qt 5's. This can be either by using qtchooser or running the proper qmake binary directly. `qmake --version` is always your friend to verify the version that is being run. On my Debian and Archlinux, the corresponding qmake binary is called `qmake-qt4`.

On a side note, it is strange that you add the `widgets` module, but you wish to remove the `gui`, whereas the former depends on the latter. Having seen the `widgets` module used in the project file, my opinion is even more clear that you probably wish to use the Qt 5 and KF 5 combination at this point in time.

Here is my working Qt 5 and KF 5 test snippet:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <KWallet>

using KWallet::Wallet;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    KWallet::Wallet* wallet = Wallet::openWallet(Wallet::LocalWallet(), 0);
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TARGET = kwallet-test
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lKF5Wallet
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KF5/KWallet
```

#### Build

```
qmake && make
```

For this to work on Ubuntu, you will need to install the following package which was added to Utopic (14.10):

```
sudo apt-get install libkf5wallet-dev
```

Unfortunately, Trusty Tahr (14.04) did not have this available, but you might be able to backport it if you wish to.

Comment: So It is not possible to build it with QT 5 and KDE 4 right? Either I use QT4 and KDE4 or QT5 and KD5? And one more question, do you know if it is possible to install it on Ubuntu? Because I couldn't find anything related to that. Thanks a lot for answer, I am gonna try it and accept your answer.

Comment: Ok, I will accept it as soon as I test it, downloading kubuntu. THanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Running c++filt over the mangled name you identified from the library gives:

`$ c++filt
_ZN7KWallet6Wallet10openWalletERK7QStringmNS0_8OpenTypeE
KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType)`

Note that the type of the second parameter here (unsigned long) does not match the declaration you provided for `KWallet::Wallt::openWallet`, which expects an unsigned long long. These are not the same type.

EDIT: Example:

```
#include <cstdio>

class QString;

namespace KWallet {
class  __attribute__((__visibility__("default"))) Wallet {
public:
    enum OpenType {
       whatever
    };
    void openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long, OpenType);


    void openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long long, OpenType);
};
}

void KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long, OpenType) {
   printf("unsigned long\n");
}

void KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long long, OpenType) {
    printf("unsigned long long\n");
}
```

Compile to a shared library:

`g++ ./madeup.cpp -shared -fPIC`

Note that the symbols mangle differently:

`nm --dynamic --defined-only ./a.out
0000000000002020 A __bss_start
0000000000002020 A _edata
0000000000002021 A _end
00000000000007d4 T _fini
0000000000000638 T _init
0000000000000786 T _ZN7KWallet6Wallet10openWalletERK7QStringmNS0_8OpenTypeE
00000000000007ac T _ZN7KWallet6Wallet10openWalletERK7QStringyNS0_8OpenTypeE`

Piping through C++ filt:

`m --dynamic --defined-only ./a.out | c++filt
0000000000002020 A __bss_start
0000000000002020 A _edata
0000000000002021 A _end
00000000000007d4 T _fini
0000000000000638 T _init
0000000000000786 T KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType)
00000000000007ac T KWallet::Wallet::openWallet(QString const&, unsigned long long, KWallet::Wallet::OpenType)`

The mangled name of the prototype seen by the application doesn't match the mangled name in the shared library that is being linked.

Comment: That looks incorrect. 0 does work if the proper linkage is set up.

Comment: @lpapp Please see my updated reply above, the issue is not with the use of the literal 0 at the call site, the issue is that the mangled name of the prototype seen by the application does not match the exported symbol from the shared library.

Comment: Ah, ok, "second parameter" was not clear to me in your original answer; thanks for the clarification. Yeah, it is possibly an issue due to the merging. WId is quintptr in Qt 5, and WId may have differed earlier, or something.